# For a bounded sequence ${a_n}$ the function $f(x)$=$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k} x^{k}$ is well defined for $-1< x <1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For a bounded sequence ${a_n}$ the function $f(x)$=$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k} x^{k}$ is well defined for $-1< x <1$

I was wondering if it is valid to use the ratio test for convergence in this case or why not(I dont really see why this test works or doesnt work at all)

In case it doesnt work by radio test for convergence  in order to prove $f(x)$=$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k} x^{k}$ is well defined for $-1< x <1$  then I need to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k} x^{k}$ converges so im not sure which order test would be useful for prove the last statement. Thanks for reading and help.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test is useful when you know something about the behaviour of the ratios $\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|$ which is not the case if $a_n$ is a general bounded sequence. Instead, you can use the [Cauchy-Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem)  theorem that provides you a formula for the radius of convergence of a power series. Assume that $|a_n| \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $M > 0$. Using the formula, you have

$$ \frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} M^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1 $$

and thus the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ satisfies $R \geq 1$ an in particular, the series converges for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: In fact the series converges uniformly on any compact subset of (-1,1), which can used to justify term-by-term integration of the series.